# azure alert chained processing

Tags: azure

need your advice on which way to choose to solve the following task: upon firing Azure alert, I need to enrich it with additional data and send summary to either/both email and Teams:

```
                                /--> Teams
Alert -> Python Script -> ... -+ 
                                \--> E-Mail
```

Simply sending alert by email is included into Alerts, but this way provides only links to Portal, which is not an option (I need to send alert to 3rd parties, which have no access to Portal; also, I need to enrich data with additional information). Integration with both Teams/Exchange365 is available in Logic App, but it doesn't allow to add intermediate script for processing and enriching data. So, the only available option seems to be Azure Function (standalone or part of Runbook), called by Alert Action Group, which then (after data processing done) will call - what? - Logic App? or directly different Webhooks (Teams / Exchange)? Other ways?

So, the question is about general knowledge - what's the most straightforward and simple way to get the task (enrich alert data and send it outside of subscription) solved? Which components of Azure offering in which sequence to use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would combine Logic Apps and functions. You can use your logic app to perform orchestration, including sending teams and email messages, you can also use it to trigger the function to run the python script.

The function integration in Logic Apps can also recieve the results of the function, so there is no need for the function to call further services, it just needs to return the data you need to the logic app, it can then consume it and pass it on however you like.

Comment: Thank you, Sam. I did exactly in this way, just not reported here - Alert triggers Function, it does all the job and then calls Logic App. There were and still are questions like which access policies need to be configured on Storage Account to work and deploy but this is already small pieces of the combined puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

The scheme, finally implemented is the following:

```
                                                       +-------+
                                                   +-->+ Teams |
 +-------+        +----------+         +-------+   |   +-------+
 | Azure |        |  Azure   |         | Logic +---+
 | Alert +--------> Function |--------->  App  |
 |       |        |          |         |       +---+
 +-------+        +----------+         +-------+   |   +-------+
                                                   +-->+ Email |
                                                       +-------+
```

where Azure Function written in Python and does all the jobs with input data, prepare input data and call Logic App, which in turn call Exchange and/or Teams using existing integrations.